# How to refresh a screen[previous] on popscreen on Blackberry OS 6

Tags: blackberry

When back button on the phone clicked, i want the previous screen to be get refreshed. Is there any events in BB 6 to refresh a previous screen on popscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Screen.onExposed()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onExposed%28%29) will be called on the previous screen, and you can refresh the values from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Also i likes to know what event i have to call to refresh whole page.

Comment: I don't think `Screen.onExposed()` is a proper callback for the asker, because API says it is also called when `this screen's application receives foreground` OR `a global screen is popped`.

Comment: True, it's not precisely what was asked for. However, if you want to keep a screen up to date after it has been hidden on the screen stack, onExposed is really the best event to do the update.   Also, you can combine the initial loading of data, and the update, into one place with this event.

Answer (score 2):

```
class FirstScreen extends MainScreen {

    private void refreshOnNextScreenClose() {
        // some code to refresh the FirstScreen on NextScreen closure
    }

    private Runnable onNextScreenCloseCallback = new Runnable() {
        refreshOnNextScreenClose();
    };

    // ..
    // somewhere in the code where you create/push NextScreen
    NextScreen nextScreen = new NextScreen(onNextScreenCloseCallback);
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
    // ..
}

class NextScreen extends MainScreen {

    private Runnable onCloseCallback;

    public NextScreen(Runnable onCloseCallback) {
        super();
        this.onCloseCallback = onCloseCallback;
    }

    public void close() {
        super.close();
        if (onCloseCallback != null) onCloseCallback.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I likes to know how to refresh a paticular potion of screen

Comment: It is unclear what do you mean under "refresh a paticular potion of screen". If you want simply to invalidate some `Field`, then just call `Field.invalidate()` on that field.